# Running "spl-stake-pool create-pool" on localhost gives error "Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist"

Tags: solana-cli, cli, stake

So I created a folder and started a local validator on it running `solana-test-validator`. In another terminal I set my url to localhost and created a new keypair file, which had enough SOL in it. I also ran `solana genesis-hash` and confirmed that it matched with the genesis hash of the local validator[image]

Now I run `spl-stake-pool create-pool --epoch-fee-numerator 5 --epoch-fee-denominator 100 --max-validators 1000 --unsafe-fees` (just the most basic version of the command) and I get the following error.`RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist` [image]

It works fine on the devnet and creates the stake pool. However I'm trying to do it on localhost because there's no airdrop rate limiting so I can experiment more.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, instead of just running `$ solana-test-validator` we need to run `$ solana-test-validator -c SPoo1Ku8WFXoNDMHPsrGSTSG1Y47rzgn41SLUNakuHy -c EmiU8AQkB2sswTxVB6aCmsAJftoowZG GDXuytm6X65R3 --url devnet --slots-per-epoch 32`